# Sketchy Wemos D1 mini Pro

Tags: wifi

Recently, I bought a ["ThingPulse ESP2866 Wifi Color Display Kit"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XZJQ7LV). I bought the kit before reading the reviews and finally read them the other day. Some of the reviews seem fake but a couple of them say that the Wemos D1 mini pro is being used to "steal credit cards" and other information. The bad reviews claimed that when they plugged the wemos into a power source, a wifi network named "ESP_xxxxxx" appears and thats how their data is stolen. I plugged the Wemos that came in my kit to a power source and a wifi network starting with "ESP..." appeard. I was wondering if this is a valid concern or if its just conspiracy. I am not very informed on cybersecurity and data security so I thought this would be the best place to ask. Please let me know if you'd like anymore information.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pure conspiracy, paranoia, or people just generally not having the slightest clue what they have bought. By default the ESP8266 is in Access Point mode, and named ESP_[last 6 chars of MAC address]. It will have an IP address in the range 192.168.4.x. And that is all.

It can't do anything else until you actually program it to do something.

Part of the "problem" is probably that the ESP8266 remembers WiFi settings independently of the sketch that is running on it. It's only the WiFi settings it remembers, though - not what to do with any data that travels over WiFi. That is purely down to whatever sketch you install.

**Unless you manually program it so it connects to your WiFi, or add extra hardware for other communications, the device can not, and will never be able to, send any data to anyone, anywhere, ever. Full stop.**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96552/discussion-on-answer-by-majenko-sketchy-wemos-d1-mini-pro).

Answer (score 0):

Before you’ve programmed the WEMOS, it will appear like an access point. It’s one if it’s great qualities of this versatile little chip. I wouldn’t worry about it. Don’t you have a secure vault for your personal info? It’s very easy to encrypt. Just search the internet on how to protect your data. You can really go it the safe way and implement a VPN. You might have to pay a 1-2$ a month for the service, which is actually a cloud based service.